# Asp.net Could not load file or assembly error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I was sent source code for a website. I have since opened it in Visual Studio Express for Web. When i try build i get Could not load file or assembly error.

The assemblies are added in the web config under assemblies section.

```
 <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.v10.1, Version=10.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v10.1, Version=10.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v10.1, Version=10.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v10.1, Version=10.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.v10.1.Export, Version=10.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
    <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraPrinting.v10.1, Version=10.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.v10.1, Version=10.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Utils.v10.1, Version=10.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
```

Can anyone explain what is the purpose fo adding them here and why i am getting this error. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have those components installed on your system?

Comment: @PhoenixReborn No, do i need to install them on the GAC?

Comment: You would need to install them _somewhere_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some third party components. You need to install the correct versions of these which may require purchasing licences for them.

The DevExpress assemblies are from [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/). DevExpress components are commercial products. They have a free trial version, but their version numbers are based on the year so the 10.1 assemblies in your config file are from 2010 and I'm not sure where you could find a free trial for that specific version.

The CrystalDecisions assemblies are part of Crystal Reports v4. I don't know enough about Crystal to know if it's all you need, but you can find the [13.0.2 installer here](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_2.exe).